# Number of possible combinations of given List with given sum dart or flutter

Tags: combinations

How to find the Number of possible combinations of a given List with a given sum dart or flutter

I have a list. [1,2,3,4,5] and sum is 5.
Expected [[4,1],[3,2]] `how to acchive`.
How to get expected [[4,1],[3,2]] which method to use to get a result.

Answer (score -1):

```
   List<List<int>> getCombinationsWithoutRepetitionAndDuplicates(
    {required List<int> arr, required int target}) {
  List<List<int>> result = [];

  void backtrack(int index, int currentSum, List<int> currentCombination) {
    if (currentSum == target) {
      result.add(List.from(currentCombination));
      return;
    }

    if (currentSum > target || index >= arr.length) {
      return;
    }

    backtrack(index + 1, currentSum, currentCombination);

    currentCombination.add(arr[index]);
    backtrack(index + 1, currentSum + arr[index], currentCombination);
    currentCombination.removeLast();
  }

  arr.sort();
  backtrack(0, 0, []);
  return result.toSet().toList();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).